# In ReactJS how would I bind "this" to the parent component inside a map() function

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs

Given the following javascript, in order to pass the `updateSelectedPages` method from the parent react component to the `Image` component inside of the `.map()` function, I first have to assign it to a variable and then use that variable inside the function.  Is there some way to bind `this` inside the function to be the parent react component so I don't have to use a temporary variable?

```
var pageNumber = 0;
var updateSelectedPages = this.updateSelectedPages;
var images = this.props.resources.map(function(resource) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var x=0; x<resource.numPages; x++) {
    pageNumber++;
    arr.push(
      <Image src={'import/previewImage/' + resource.encodedName + '?page=' + pageNumber} number={pageNumber} updateSelectedPages={updateSelectedPages} key={pageNumber} />
    );
  }
  return arr;
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
```

Comment: Or you could just declare a top level variable `self` and set it to `this` and access it within the function :)

Comment: @DhruvaSagar i'm not sure it's gonna work 100%. Look at answers for better alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind `this` as follows:

```
var pageNumber = 0;
var images = this.props.resources.map(function(resource) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var x=0; x<resource.numPages; x++) {
    pageNumber++;
    arr.push(
      <Image src={'import/previewImage/' + resource.encodedName + '?page=' + pageNumber} number={pageNumber} updateSelectedPages={this.updateSelectedPages} key={pageNumber} />
    );
  }
  return arr;
}.bind(this)).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
```

Comment: That was easy :)  I didn't realize a Function had a bind() method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Array.prototype.map take second argument that set the context for the callback function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

So the following should be enough, if I understood you question correctly :)

```
var pageNumber = 0;
var images = this.props.resources.map(function(resource) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var x=0; x<resource.numPages; x++) {
    pageNumber++;
    arr.push(
      <Image src={'import/previewImage/' + resource.encodedName + '?page=' + pageNumber} number={pageNumber} updateSelectedPages={this.updateSelectedPages} key={pageNumber} />
    );
  }
  return arr;
}, this).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
```

**Edit 2+ years later:**
Nowadays you can most likely utilize arrow functions in your code (either by native support if only targeting the latest browser or via build-tools like babel), and other than being shorter to write they also have lexical scoping for `this` which [removes the need for binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) or passing the second arg to `array.map()`

```
let pageNumber = 0;
const images = this.props.resources.map(resource => { // <-- using arrow function removes the need to worry about `this`
  const arr = [];
  for(let x = 0; x < resource.numPages; x++) {
    pageNumber++;
    arr.push(
      <Image
        src={`import/previewImage/${resource.encodedName}?page=${pageNumber}`}
        number={pageNumber}
        updateSelectedPages={this.updateSelectedPages}
        key={pageNumber}
      />
    );
  }
  return arr;
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
```

Comment: This tends to be a better approach than the answer which is marked correct because this avoids an additional function call, and is therefore a little quicker.